# Add static navbar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to learn some front-end development and I found an interesting thing [HERE][1]. I would like to keep the sliding effect whenever I move the cursor to left or right, but the navbar to be static/fixed.

```
  [1]: https://codepen.io/bradtraversy/pen/dJzzdB
```

Comment: Just remove the event listeners in the JS and it won't move.

Comment: @shubham - i want to use those animations.

Comment: You want the animations? the event listeners are making the navbar move left and right. you want these to move? Please make your question more clear.

Comment: I want to keep the sliding effect when I move to left or right, but the navbar to be static.

Comment: There is no navbar in the link you posted. show the code with navbar.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

https://codepen.io/mikehavoc/pen/KQzgQG/

```
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
 <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)
</span></a>
      </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>


 <div class="container">
   <div class="split left">
      <h1>The Designer</h1>
     <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
    </div>
   <div class="split right">
     <h1>The Programmer</h1>
     <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS to make fixed navbar

```
nav{
position:fixed !important;
width:100% !important
}
```

```css
nav{
position:fixed !important;
width:100% !important
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Collapsible Navbar</h3>
  <p>In this example, the navigation bar is hidden on small screens and replaced by a button in the top right corner (try to re-size this window).
  <p>Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed.</p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px">
  <h3>Fixed Navbar</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p>
      <p>A fixed navigation bar stays visible in a fixed position (top or bottom) independent of the page scroll.</p> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Scroll this page to see the effect</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

with bootstrap use easily make fixed navvbar with class `navbar-fixed-top`
top specifies position of navbar

[example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_fixed&stacked=h)